# iPhone SSL Website Certificate Warning

Tags: iphone, firefox, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a few sites that have SSL Certificates installed. When an SSL request is made with my employer's iPhone, this error message is displayed:

> Accept Website Certificate
>
> The certificate for this website is invalid. Tap Accept to connect to this website anyway.

I've pulled up the same pages in other browsers, including Safari, and they do not show any issues with the certs.

These two URLs exhibit the problem:

1. https://www.powerlunchbunch.com/index.php?template=join&nav=20
2. https://www.councilonagingmartin.org/index.php?template=donate&nav=257

---

**Additional Information:**

1. Both SSL certs are issued by Network Solutions
2. The sites are hosted on Rackspace Cloud Sites

---

**Update:**

I now have an open ticket with Rackspace for this issue.  I browsed the same sites in Firefox 4.0 Beta 7, and got this warning page, telling me that "The certificate is not trusted because no issuer chain was provided.":
[image: Firefox 4.0 Beta 7 SSL Chain Cert Warning]

Comment: are these sites using self signed certificates?  If not, what CA are they from?  The iPhone doesnt trust the certificate, so its throwing you an error

Comment: Updated my post to answer your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's because you (or your hosting company) haven't configured the full certificate chain on your web server.

Take a look at a report from an ssl checker, such as this:

http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=www.councilonagingmartin.org

...

I can see from this report that you're using Apache2.2. Configuring  'intermediate certificates' on Apache2 goes something like this:

SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/crt/yourDOMAINNAME.crt

SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/crt/private.key

**SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/crt/chainCert.xxx**

I don't know if you configured the certificate yourself, or your hosting company configured it, so you'll either need to contact your hosting company, or the certificate provider, who can provide the intermediate certificate(s).

Hope That Helps

Comment: Thanks! I will be contacting my hosting company.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the Root CA for both those certificates, Network Solutions, L.L.C. is not a trusted certificate authority on the iPhone.

If you look at the certificate chain, it does end up at AddTrust, which is a trusted CA on the iPhone.

So you likely have one of the following problems:

1) Your certificate is not installed correctly on the web server

2) You need to work with Network Solutions (the SSL cert issuer) to get a cert that properly chains to AddTrust.